# Как добавить исключение для программы в брандмауэр на Windows 7 через реестр?

Tags: windows, реестр, firewall

Я пытаюсь обойти всплывающее окно брандмауэра при попытке подключения самодельной программы, написанной на Си, к FTP-серверу. Есть ли какая-то определённая ветка в реестре, куда нужно сунуть определённое значение? Можно ли вообще добавить исключение для программы, не используя netsh или "Брандмауэр Windows в режиме повышенной безопасности"? Если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Allow Curl" dir=in action=allow program="%ProgramFiles%\curl\curl.exe"` не?

Comment: @donRumata получается, что это единственный способ...

Comment: Ваш вопрос звучит примерно так: Как нарушить систему защиты от несанкционированного использования компьютера с Windows? UAC откажет в доступе при обычном обращении и через реестр. Предлагаю воспользоваться стандартными средствами повышения привилегий в Windows: настроить права на момент установки приложения; настроить триггеры, обеспечивающие нужный доступ (через Планировщик задач); возложить на пользователя обязанность по подтверждению доступа; вообще отключить UAC.

Comment: @rusnuker, ну так а что не нравится-то?